# Attach to MVC 6 process in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am hosting an asp.net 5/mvc 6 application in local IIS using dnx x64 1.0.0.rc1.  I would like to attach to the iis process and debug my application, but no symbols are ever loaded for the classes that I set breakpoints in.

Is this possible with this version of dnx and IIS?
If so, how do I attach to the iis process with symbols loaded?

---UPDATE

So I've tried attaching to dnx.exe, but still no luck.  Strangely, I was able to get this to work one time, but cannot replicate it again.  So if anyone can outline the steps required to debug MVC 6 on IIS, please post here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What process are you trying to attach to? I believe you should be attaching to dnx.exe

Comment: I was trying to connect to w3wp.exe, but that wasn't working.  It appears that attaching to dnx.exe works.  Thanks!

Comment: so it appeared to work before, but now I can't hit a breakpoint.  Can you detail the steps needed in order to allow debugging by attaching to dnx.exe?

Comment: Out of interest, if you run iisreset.exe and try again, do your breakpoints get hit? And are the symbols being loaded?

Comment: no luck - symbols are not being loaded.  Do I have to do a special type of plublish (ie, using dnu publish) or set anything special up in iis?

Comment: Might be a silly question but is your application actually running? I.e, have you browsed to its url so the application is loaded? I find it strange why it was working before and not now

Comment: yeah - it is running.  I can browse to my localhost (iis) url and hit the pages.  The strange thing is that if I start my application (by using F5), then attach to the dnx process, I can load the localhost iis url in a browser and hit my breakpoints.....strange.

Comment: I think I had an environment issue on my local machine.  Now it is working fine connecting to the dnx.exe process.

Comment: With the most recent release of ASP.NET Core 1.0 - you need to look for "dotnet.exe" now.

Comment: I don't see w3wp.exe, dnx.exe, or dotnet.exe. Has this changed again?